# How to pass multiCapabilities from gulp-angular-protractor

Tags: gulp, protractor

I need to pass multiCapabilities from gulp-angular-protractor.
Following is my requirement:

```
multiCapabilities: [
{
browserName : 'internet explorer',
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'
},
{
browserName : 'chrome',
seleniumAddress: 'http://172.23.230.198:4444/wd/hub'
}
```

I tried following but its throwing error

```
gulp.src([])
.pipe(gulpProtractorAngular({
'configFile': './conf.js',
'debug': true,
'autoStartStopServer': false,
args: [
'--specs', './testExecution/UserManagement/Login/*.js',
'--multiCapabilities.0.browserName', 'internet explorer',
'--multiCapabilities.1.browserName', 'chrome'
],
keepAlive: true
}))
.on('error', function (e) {
console.log("specs: " + specs);
console.log(e);
process.exit(1);
return new gutil.PluginError("ERROR", "Error", {showStack: true});
})
.on('end', function (){
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:
You need to add multiCapabilities argument in lib/cli.js, below is the code:

```
if(argv.multiCapabilities) {
   var multiCapabilitiesArray = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(argv.multiCapabilities).length; i++) {
     multiCapabilitiesArray[i] = flattenObject(argv.multiCapabilities[i]);
   }
   argv.multiCapabilities = multiCapabilitiesArray;
 }
```

Then you can pass multiCapabilities as arguments from gulp-angular-protractor as required

```
args: [
'--specs', './testExecution/UserManagement/Login/*.js',
'--multiCapabilities.0.browserName', 'internet explorer',
'--multiCapabilities.1.browserName', 'chrome'
]
```

Hope this helps!